# No sound after clean Windows 10 install

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I finally upgraded my main system from Windows 7 (rest in peace) to Windows 10 Enterprise 1909. The system is an old Sandy Bridge chip (aka 2nd Generation i3-2100), but the installation went smoothly except for one problem - even after installing all Windows updates, there's no audio at all. The audio icon in the tray shows up as being disabled, and clicking on it runs a Troubleshooter which concludes that there's no audio device plugged in (there is).

Going to Device Manager shows two instances of `High Definition Audio Device`, and trying to automatically update the drivers for these tells me that the best version is already installed.

How can I fix my sound?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [manual for my motherboard](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/H61M-HVS.pdf) shows that the audio codec is provided by VIA, but looking at the [drivers available for it](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H61M-HVS/index.asp#Download) shows no VIA drivers at all for Windows 10.

This was confirmed by checking [VIA's own Drivers Portal](http://download.viatech.com/en/support/driversSelect.jsp) - for whatever reason, it seems that VIA never bothered to release any audio drivers at all for Windows 10.

Instead, I tried the next best thing, and downloaded the most recent version of the VIA High Definition Audio driver available from the [motherboard's manufacturer](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H61M-HVS/index.asp#Download), which is for Windows 8.1. I then went into Device Manager, selected one of the `High Definition Audio Device` instances, and updated it manually by browsing to the folder containing the downloaded VIA driver for Windows 8.1. This time the install completes successfully, and after a restart, the audio works exactly as expected.

Unfortunately, trying to upgrade the second `High Definition Audio Device` in the same way doesn't work, and I'm still confused about what that device could be since the motherboard's manual lists no other audio devices, but this is just an aside and doesn't bother me too much now that my audio is working as it should.

Comment: If you're really stuck on the drivers you can get a really simple USB i/o device for $£€ 2 on eBay etc. They all tend to work on the same structure, immediately recognised by the OS. They're not great, but they function. Just search "USB soundcard" & sort by cheapest for a bare minimum device.